# Django transaction failure for nested atomic blocks and concurrent processes on MySQL

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, transactions

I've faced following issue and I'm not entirely sure it's a django or MySQL issue. 
It happens when I want to retry django's save method in case of database error such as deadlock. Lets not focus on how ugly it is because it was just temporary hack which revealed potentially another problem.

To reproduce it I've prepared a script that runs 3 concurrent processes and simulate database failure by raising AssertionError.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models, transaction
from time import sleep
from django.db.utils import OperationalError


class ModelA(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        def save_record(attempt):
            print attempt
            try:
                with transaction.atomic():
                    super(ModelA, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
                    if attempt > 1:
                        assert False
            except (AssertionError, OperationalError):
                # dirty hack to retry
                sleep(1)
                if attempt > 0:
                    save_record(attempt-1)
                else:
                    raise

        save_record(5)
```

**test script**

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.db import transaction

from atomic import models


@transaction.atomic
def create_record():
    a = models.ModelA()
    a.name = "test {}".format(time.time())
    a.save()


class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        procs = []
        for i in range(3):
            p = Process(target=create_record)
            procs.append(p)

        for p in procs:
            p.start()

        for p in procs:
            p.join()
```

If I run only 1 process everything works but with 3 concurrent processes 1 works (saves data) and another 2 fails with following traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/blue/.virtualenvs/atomictest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 371, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/django/atomictest/atomic/management/commands/test_atomic.py", line 14, in create_record
    a.save()
  File "/media/django/atomictest/atomic/models.py", line 29, in save
    save_record(5)
  File "/media/django/atomictest/atomic/models.py", line 25, in save_record
    save_record(attempt-1)
  File "/media/django/atomictest/atomic/models.py", line 25, in save_record
    save_record(attempt-1)
  File "/media/django/atomictest/atomic/models.py", line 25, in save_record
    save_record(attempt-1)
  File "/media/django/atomictest/atomic/models.py", line 18, in save_record
    super(ModelA, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/blue/.virtualenvs/atomictest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 545, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/blue/.virtualenvs/atomictest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 573, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/home/blue/.virtualenvs/atomictest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 635, in _save_table
    forced_update)
  File "/home/blue/.virtualenvs/atomictest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 679, in _do_update
    return filtered._update(values) > 0
  File "/home/blue/.virtualenvs/atomictest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 510, in _update
    return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(None)
  File "/home/blue/.virtualenvs/atomictest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 980, in execute_sql
    cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)
  File "/home/blue/.virtualenvs/atomictest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 786, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/blue/.virtualenvs/atomictest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 69, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/blue/.virtualenvs/atomictest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 47, in execute
    self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()
  File "/home/blue/.virtualenvs/atomictest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 372, in validate_no_broken_transaction
    "An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't "
TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.
```

I use django 1.6.5 and MySQL 5.5.37. Tested also with sqlite and postgres and there's no such issue with those backends.
I've also noticed that this happends only with nested atomic blocks. If i remove @transaction.atomic decorator from create_record() function it works again.

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid [catching exceptions inside atomic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/transactions/):

> When exiting an atomic block, Django looks at whether it’s exited
>   normally or with an exception to determine whether to commit or roll
>   back. If you catch and handle exceptions inside an atomic block, you
>   may hide from Django the fact that a problem has happened. This can
>   result in unexpected behavior.
>
> This is mostly a concern for DatabaseError and its subclasses such as
>   IntegrityError. After such an error, the transaction is broken and
>   Django will perform a rollback at the end of the atomic block. If you
>   attempt to run database queries before the rollback happens, Django
>   will raise a TransactionManagementError. You may also encounter this
>   behavior when an ORM-related signal handler raises an exception.
>
> The correct way to catch database errors is around an atomic block as
>   shown above. If necessary, add an extra atomic block for this purpose.
>   This pattern has another advantage: it delimits explicitly which
>   operations will be rolled back if an exception occurs.
>
> If you catch exceptions raised by raw SQL queries, Django’s behavior
>   is unspecified and database-dependent.

In this case you're catching `DataBaseError`s inside the `create_record`'s `atomic` block.

You should move your save retry attempt logic to the `create_record` method.

```
def create_record(retry=5):
    instance = models.ModelA(name="test {}".format(time.time()))
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            instance.save()
    except DataBaseError:
        if retry:
            time.sleep(1)
            create_record(retry-1)
        else:
            raise
```

And avoid overriding `models.Model.save`.

Comment: I don't think your explanation is correct. Firstly you removed nested atomic block which is a reason of my problem. Secondly according to django's documentation my case should work. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly

Nested atomic block in save method should rollback transaction to save point and then try save again.

Comment: What happen if you use `transaction.atomic()` as a context manager inside the `create_record` instead of wrapping it?

Comment: That doesn't change anything - still the same problem